# Non-standard activity lifecycle on Moto G?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I am developing Android apps and use a Nexus 7 and a Moto G as testing targets. Using a very simple test app I noticed that on the Moto G the activity life cycle does not include the onRestart()-Method, in contrary to the Nexus (and the AVDs as well). Has anybody made a similar experience!

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that due to lower memory availability, and more aggressive memory management on the Moto G, that your app is being terminated instead of just being stopped.

Instead of seeing an onRestart() are you seeing an onCreate()? If so, that would match the application life cycle diagrams.